# Locking accounts using the same strong hash in the database

Tags: hash, brute-force

A website has some bruteforce prevention for logins, and I need to turn that off because it's buggy and it's causing problems. It will stay turned off, probably forever, because there are no plans to do any maintenance on that website. It's a small company's website, there are only a few users (maybe about 10), and most of them (if not all) basically never log in. The last activity from the owner is probably from years ago. So yeah, it's pretty much half abandoned.

Now, if I just turn off the bruteforce prevention system, I am afraid I will potentially increase the risk of compromise, if any of the users happened to have weak passwords. I believe the risk will only increase slightly, because the system just bans the IP temporarily after a few failed attempts, so you still can get 10s or 100s attempts per day anyway, and if you really have a weak password I feel it won't help much. However I still feel that just turning off the bruteforce prevention system is not the right thing to do.

So I thought of this quick solution: **disable the bruteforce prevention system, and change every password hash in the database with the same hash, calculated from a very strong password** that I won't keep anywhere (create it and forget it). As a result, every user will have the same hash (same salt and same password) stored in the database. However, nobody can log in, because nobody knows the password (not even me) and the password is very strong. To log in, they will have to click on "I forgot my password" and create a new one. So I will just tell the company that the bruteforce prevention system has been disabled, but all their accounts have been "locked" to prevent increasing the risk in case some users are using weak passwords. If anybody wants to log in (to continue using their half abandoned website), they can click on "I forgot my password" and **make sure the new password is strong enough** (and I might give them tips or examples about what a strong password is).

Question: is anything wrong with my reasoning? Does this solution make sense? The only possible weak point I see is that I use the same hash for every user in the database (so every user will have the same salt and same password), because it's easier and faster to do so. However, I can't see how this weakness could be attacked, since the password won't be known or used by anybody, and it will be very strong (so bruteforcing the hash, even offline, should be out of the question). Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fine. Practically, the chance that such random password was bruteforced would be zero.

However, the way to do this would usually be slightly different: rather than setting it to a valid hash, you set it to something invalid. I wouldn't be surprised if the password implementation was a custom one, so you should check what it is doing, but basically, if it checks that `hash(salt, provided_password) == stored_hash` you would set `stored_hash` to something like `!` which won't be equal to *any* hash output.

This lets you perform the same without having that *weakness*. I would prefer this for being cleaner, as it more clearly separates the representation of accounts which are locked from those with real hashes.

Comment: +1 moreover pre-pending a ! to the hash is Linux /etc/shadow locks accounts, so it's something of a standard. It's also easy to unlock an account by simply removing the !.

Comment: Although I didn't detail it, that's why I suggested a `!` and not another character :)